# How/When do I initialize a Fragment added via XML?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a 2 pane view that is defined in XML. For xlarge, the left side of the view is a Fragment that deals with content selection. I want to initialize this selector `ListFragment` to have the first item highlighted on app start up.

I've written a method in the `ListFragment` to do this:

```
public void setSelectedItem (int position) {
    //Unselect the previous item
    if(mPreviousPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        View oldSelected = getListView().getChildAt(mPreviousPosition);
        oldSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button);
        ((ImageView) oldSelected.findViewById(R.id.selector_icon)).setImageDrawable(icons.getDrawable(mPreviousPosition));
        ((TextView) oldSelected.findViewById(R.id.selector_text)).setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.text_selector);
    }

    //Select this item
    View newSelected = getListView().getChildAt(position);
    newSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_active);
    ((ImageView) newSelected.findViewById(R.id.selector_icon)).setImageDrawable(icons_active.getDrawable(position));
    ((TextView) newSelected.findViewById(R.id.selector_text)).setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.text_selector_active);

    mPreviousPosition = position;
}
```

When I call this after an item has been selected, it works great. But when I try highlight the first item on startup, I get a NPE at

```
newSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_active);
```

It seems `getListView().getChildAt(position)` is returning `null` because the Fragment's view hasn't been created yet.

So, from where in my Activity is it safe to try initialise the `ListFragment`? I've tried in onStart, onRestoreInstanceState and onResume but they all produce the NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you have two panes (left pane is ListFragment) and these two fragments are held within a FragmentActivity. The fragments are being set in the xml layout for the FragmentActivity. The fragments are available to the FragmentActivity following the onAttach() cycle but this doesn't necessarily mean that the view elements in the child fragment are available yet.

First question is where are you trying to set the selected item? In the FragmentActivity or in the ListFragment? It should be handled in the ListFragment in the onResume() method.

I take it that based on the selection in the ListFragment you are then populating the right fragment with data for the selection. You will probably want to look at this link which will give you a good example of using listeners to avoid dependancies between the fragment activity and underlying fragments

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You can then use listeners to handle the selection in the ListFragment and pass the selection to the right fragment. In the right fragment you can check for a selection in the FragmentActivity as well as register the fragment to listen for selections. This way you should cover the situation where the selection is fired before the right fragment has registered as a listener.

**UDPATE**

Look at responsive layout design for further information but here are some starting points.

```
/res
    /values
       bool.xml
    /values-sw600dp-land
       bools.xml
```

Then inside the bools.xml file define a value for isDualPane

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isDualPane">[true/false]</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in your code in the listFragment you can then reference bools resource and know what the layout is.

```
isDualPane = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isDualPane);
```

You also have the benefit of using this in any class to know what the layout is and without needing to create dependancies between classes.

Here are some links that might help.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html

Comment: The left pane is a Fragment defined in xml. The right pane is a FrameLayout. I was trying to set the selected item from the FragmentActivity. I agree the Fragment should initialise itself but it doesn't know whether it is in a 1-pane or 2-pane view, and I only want to show a selected item if it's a 2-pane view. I guess the Fragment could ask the FragmentActivity whether to show the selected item in `onAttach` or something. Setting the content of the right pane isn't the problem. The problem is whether the left pane Fragment to initialise for single pane or double pane.

Comment: How are you handling the definition on single pane or two pane layout? Are you using a bool value in the /res subfolders? This way you can query the bool value and know if it is single pane or two pane layout.

Comment: not a bad idea. At the moment I'm using a single pane layout for normal/large and a 2-pane layout for xlarge. Then I findViewById for the FrameLayout. If it's not null I know I'm in 2 pane mode.

Comment: updated the answer with more info on this. Check out the first link for some valuable information. Will save you a lot of time and effort in trying to handle the difference between double and single panes and manipulating all the code. I have implemented this and the code is nice and clean with no code dependencies between fragments and fragment activity. Makes it a lot cleaner, more flexible, and easier to manage.

Comment: I think your edit is a good idea. My only concern is that it feels like I'm replicating data when I maybe don't have to, like a denormalised database. Perhaps this is the best way to do it but it does leave the door open for inconsistency

Comment: I am not sure how you are replicating data? You still only have one fragment for each pane(the same list fragment is used whether it is single or double pane layout), there is a little more xml to write. But in the code your ListFragment checks the bool value and uses that to flag whether to select the list item or not. The selection then fires a listener which triggers the frame layout to populate with the data instruction. The left pane fragment will initialise itself depending on the bool value. Can you explain how you think it will replicate data please, not sure I understand fully?

Comment: I would be carrying info about whether the view is 2-pane or 1-pane in 2 different places, i.e. in the layout and in a boolean resource. So, if I changed either the boolean or the layout, it would produce inconsistent bahaviour. It's not a train-smash. It feels like a 95% solution to me. I'll accept thought because it's good.

Comment: Using the boolean means you don't need to handle the 1-pane/2-pane situation. That is the beauty of it. The device uses the boolean value automatically determining which fragmentActivity layout to use. if you need to check for pane status you just check the boolean. Everything happens automagically but you need to make sure there is no dependency in your code between the two fragments (which there shouldn't be anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify in wich fragment callback you populate your ListView.
Anyway this the diagram that compares activity state and  fragment state, maybe could help you:

[image: activity state compared to fragment state]

Comment: In the selector (`ListFragment`) I call `setListAdapter(new SelectorAdapter());` during `onCreate`. The ListFragment then populates the ListView automatically during `onCreateView`. The diagram is interesting but I've already tried to activate the list items in the Activity's `onStart` and `onResume` which should be fine according to the image